# Seeking generalized way to solve equation using all possible combinations of values of two lists in python

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, iteration, simulation

i want to see which combinations of the product of each of these lists solves an equation, "j=k-l+m"

```
stake=[0,2,5,10]
odds=[1,2,5,10]
```

The only way i can think of so far is as follows. I create a list of tuples using product function like so

```
from itertools import product

stake_odds=(list(product(stake,odds)))
print(stake_odds)
>>>[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 5), (0, 10), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 5), (2, 10), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 5), (5, 10), (10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 5), (10, 10)]
```

i then create a further list of the combinations of tuples of length the number of variables in my equation:

```
stake_odds2=(list(product(stake_odds, repeat=3)))
```

then I do the following

```
pos_combos=[]
for i in stake_odds2:
    x,y,z=i
    a,b=x
    c,d=y
    e,f=z
    k=a*b
    l=c*d
    m=e*f
    j=k-l+m
    if j > 0:
        pos_combos.append(i)
```

printing *pos_combos* returns what i want. My issue is however is that if i want to expand the equation or the two lists then it obviously becomes a nightmare to unpack the tuples and label everything, even the above is giving me a headache looking at it.

Is there any slicker way of doing this? maybe any simulation packages i should be aware of?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to unpack all of those variables, just take the product of the tuples then do the final math.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
stake=[0,2,5,10]
odds=[1,2,5,10]
stake_odds=(list(product(stake,odds)))
stake_odds2=(list(product(stake_odds, repeat=3)))

for i in stake_odds2:
    t = [np.prod(x) for x in i]
    if t[0]-t[1]+t[2]>0:
        pos_combos.append(i)
```